# Using Ternary operators with filter function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and am starting with Javascript with a 30 Day vanilla javascript coding challenge from Wes Bos.
I want to know why this works perfectly

```
const in1500 = inventors.filter((a)=>{if(a.year>=1500 && a.year<1600) return 1})
console.table(in1500)
```

this gives a blank result

```
const in1500 = inventors.filter((a)=>{(a.year>=1500 && a.year<1600) ? 1 : -1})
console.table(in1500)
```

and this gives me the whole array

```
const in1500 = inventors.filter((a)=>(a.year>=1500 && a.year<1600) ? 1 : -1)
console.table(in1500)
//I just removed the angular brackets
```

Comment: @gorak thanks! I replaced 1 and -1 with true and false, and it worked! Your solution worked too!

Answer (score 3):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) expects a value which can be converted to `true` for items in the result array.

Return values which can be converted to `false` are filterd out.

Your approaches:

1. [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with a function block returns `undefined` by default. You return `1` which is a [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value (like any number without zero or NaN, every non empty string, every array or object or function, and of course `true`), what meas this value can be converted to `true`.
2. Here you have a function block and return nothing. The default value is `undefined`, which is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (like `false`, zero, `NaN`, `''`, null), the opposite of *truthy*.
3. You simply return a *truthy* value (as both `1` and `-1` is truthy), all items are in the result set.

The shortest approach is to use an arrow function without function block and return just the result of the condition.

```
const in1500 = inventors.filter(a => a.year >= 1500 && a.year < 1600);
```

A use of a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside of the function is superfluous, because you need to return either a *truthy* or *falsy* value, which is more code and does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

in the second case, you have not given a return, that's why it's giving a empty result.

```
let inventors = [1500, 1501, 1505, 1550];
let in15001 = inventors.filter((a) => {
  if (a.year >= 1500 && a.year < 1600){ return 1}
  else return -1;
})
console.log(in15001)

let in15002 = inventors.filter((a) => {
  return (a.year >= 1500 && a.year < 1600) ? 1 : -1
})
console.log(in15002)


let in15003 = inventors.filter((a) => (a.year >= 1500 && a.year < 1600) ? 1 : -1)
console.log(in15003)
```